# Unwanted W8080 warnings from TeeChart component in CBuilder XE8

Tags: c++builder, teechart, c++builder-xe8

When compiling a project under CBuilder XE8 that uses the TeeChart components distributed with that IDE, I get long reams of errors like this:

```
[bcc32 Warning] GdiplusStringFormat.h(306): W8058 Cannot create pre-compiled header: initialized data in header
[bcc32 Warning] MI3Proc.cpp(719): W8080 'Gdiplus::FlatnessDefault' is declared but never used
[bcc32 Warning] MI3Proc.cpp(719): W8080 'Gdiplus::GenericSansSerifFontFamily' is declared but never used
[bcc32 Warning] MI3Proc.cpp(719): W8080 'Gdiplus::GenericSerifFontFamily' is declared but never used
[bcc32 Warning] MI3Proc.cpp(719): W8080 'Gdiplus::GenericMonospaceFontFamily' is declared but never used
[bcc32 Warning] MI3Proc.cpp(719): W8080 'Gdiplus::GenericSansSerifFontFamilyBuffer' is declared but never used
[bcc32 Warning] MI3Proc.cpp(719): W8080 'Gdiplus::GenericSerifFontFamilyBuffer' is declared but never used
[bcc32 Warning] MI3Proc.cpp(719): W8080 'Gdiplus::GenericMonospaceFontFamilyBuffer' is declared but never used
[bcc32 Warning] MI3Proc.cpp(719): W8080 'Gdiplus::GenericTypographicStringFormatBuffer' is declared but never used
[bcc32 Warning] MI3Proc.cpp(719): W8080 'Gdiplus::GenericDefaultStringFormatBuffer' is declared but never used
```

This problem is also reported on Steema's support forum at http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15374, but there is no followup.

I had a similar issue with TeeChart under CBuilder 4 (something like 20 years ago!). Hmmm.

I don't want to turn off the W8080 warning project-wide, as it helps keep my code clean, but is there any way to turn off the warnings just for the TeeChart unit?

Additionally, I'm not sure what to make of the W8058 error. The `#pragma hdrstop` precedes the include of `VclTee.TeeGDIPlus.hpp`, so this error should not be occurring.

EDIT:
Some more information I've discovered is that the offending variables are static/const global variable declared and initialized in GdiplusEnums.h and GdiplusHeaders.h (files copyright 2001 by Microsoft).

Temporarily disabling the 8080 warning does not work because somewhere in the chain of nested includes, the 8080 warning is reset to default. If you disable the 8080 warning in the call to the compiler (i.e. global options), then all 8080 warnings will cease, but then you don't catch your own mistakes. Even putting the entire cpp unit in a `#pragma warn -8080` block will not stop the warnings!

The only way I've found to stop the warnings (without globally disabling the 8080 warning) is to put dummy code like this somewhere in each affected source unit (so that the variables **are** referenced).

```
   void           *pvDummy;
   double         dDummy;
   BYTE           *pBYTEDummy;

   dDummy = Gdiplus::FlatnessDefault;
   pvDummy = Gdiplus::GenericSansSerifFontFamily;
   pvDummy = Gdiplus::GenericSerifFontFamily;
   pvDummy = Gdiplus::GenericMonospaceFontFamily;
   pBYTEDummy = Gdiplus::GenericSansSerifFontFamilyBuffer;
   pBYTEDummy = Gdiplus::GenericSerifFontFamilyBuffer;
   pBYTEDummy = Gdiplus::GenericMonospaceFontFamilyBuffer;
   pBYTEDummy = Gdiplus::GenericTypographicStringFormatBuffer;
   pBYTEDummy = Gdiplus::GenericDefaultStringFormatBuffer;
```

The method containing this code has to be in a #pragma warn -8004 block to avoid warnings about "xxx is assigned a value that is never used". Grrr.

This does offend some sense of good coding style, but there you go...

Comment: The W8058 is, in my experience, never where it should be. This usually means that somewhere else, you are declaring some data. Some times it shows up in default string parameters, or things like that that work fine (i.e., don't produce this warning) in other headers. I have *never* seen it  point where the problem is, usually not even in the correct header. You could try commenting #includes before the "culprit" header and see if it stops, and then looking for instance for Extended consts, which at least for me usually cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the W8080 (or any other warning) using the `#pragma warn` directive.

I would add it before the header that produces the warnings, so you don't modify the header. For example:

```
#pragma warn -8080
#include <TheOffendingHeader.h>
#pragma warn .8080
```

Comment: Using the method you suggest does not work because XE8 reinserts the #include outside the pragma block. See my OP for some additional information.

Comment: @EBlake I don't have XE8 at hand to try, but I don't quite understand why or where does the compiler includes it outside of where you ask it to. Are you sure you don't have a precompiled header being used for that project? With XE5 at least when creating a new project, it usually creates a header for PCH that is included/inserted automatically at the start of every unit.

Comment: What I meant was that the include is managed by XE - it's one of those header file includes at the beginning of your unit header. When you add a component to a form, XE adds the releavant header file include automatically. If you try deleting them (or apparently putting them in a #pragma block), XE will simply re-insert them. See edit in OP for more info.

Comment: Ok, you can try anyway adding that *before* the include of your form. Doing so will preprocesses the offending file with the warning disabled, and then, the automatically inserted include will not get processed because it was already done (the header guard should take care of this)

Comment: As I mentioned my edit above, even enclosing the entire source unit in the pragma warn -8080 block does not work. Clearly somewhere in the Embarcadero-provided nested include chain, the warning is getting set back to default (i.e. there is a #pragma warn .8080 or equivalent somewhere in the include chain).

Comment: "does not work because XE8 reinserts the #include outside" - same here